# Generating an address from a private key in Java?

Tags: address, private-key, java

I'd like to write a function in Java that takes a private key and generates the address to use in a QR code. I'd like to make this , but I'm not very good with the hashing algorithms.

I've checked with https://www.bitaddress.org and what is generated on there is not the same as what I'm getting in my program.

Can anyone help me with this? Google has failed me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use an existing library. [bitcoinj](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/) for instance provides the method `getPubKeyHash` of the class `ECKey` which does what you are looking for.

**Edit**: `getPubKeyHash` does not return the human readable address directly, but can be used to create an instance of the class `Address`. This (as a subclass of `VersionedChecksummedBytes`) has in turn the method `toString` which presents the hash as bitcoin address.

Comment: But isn't that only the hash, and not the address? And I've tried using that library, it gives me errors, like java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory, which I'll have to find myself I guess :(

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right. See my edit.

I haven't used bitcoinj yet, so I'm afraid I can't help you with the installation.

Comment: Everything should be included in the two jar files.  Make sure you have bitcoinj.jar and bitcoinj-tools.jar in your classpath.  The error you received sounds like bitcoinj-tools.jar is missing.

Comment: Yup you're right. And if anyone wants to see how I did this:
  Address address = new Address(NetworkParameters.prodNet(), Utils.sha256hash160(new ECKey(privkey, null).getPubKey())); Then toString() gives the readable address.